# UIMotionEffect same time not work in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, ios7, parallax, uicollectionviewcell, core-motion

i add motion effect on cell subview.
first time it's worked fine.
but when cell reused. the motion effect not work....

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
testcell *processingCell = (testcell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
    horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-kMotionEffectRelativeValue );
    horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(kMotionEffectRelativeValue );
    UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
    verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-kMotionEffectRelativeValue );
    verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(kMotionEffectRelativeValue );
    group = [[UIMotionEffectGroup alloc] init];
    group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect,verticalMotionEffect];

});

if (!processingCell.coustomView) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    view.center = processingCell.contentView.center;
    view.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    [processingCell addSubview:view];
    processingCell.coustomView = view;
}
processingCell.coustomView.hidden = YES;
processingCell.coustomView.hidden = NO;
[processingCell.coustomView addMotionEffect:group];
return processingCell;
```

}

if i want hidden this subview. and after show it . then the motion effect useless

```
processingCell.coustomView.hidden = YES;
processingCell.coustomView.hidden = NO;
```

i try to use this debug motion Effect .the subView is suspended

po [UIView _motionEffectEngine]

https://github.com/sipdar/parallax-effect-Bug

Comment: You should provide more information e.g. what have you tried, what is the error, logs,...

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm doing something pretty similar and also finding that it doesn't work. Your code isn't guarding against the same motion effect being added to a cell multiple times (when a cell is re-used), which you should do. I am doing that, and I'm still getting the same problem though.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by subclassing UICollectionViewCell and removing and re-applying the motion effect during layout. Example:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self addMotionEffectToView:self.contentView];
}

- (void) addMotionEffectToView:(UIView*) view{

    for (UIMotionEffect* effect in [view.motionEffects copy]){
        [view removeMotionEffect:effect];
    }
    ... add your motion effect
}
```

Comment: Good hint. And don't forget to reload the visible cells when you reenter the screen.